# How to position mat-select-trigger inside the select field with Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I would like to use either :

```
<mat-select-trigger>
   <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
</mat-select-trigger>
```

or

```
<button mat-icon-button matSuffix>
<mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
</button>
```

to clear select mat-form-field with Angular Material but with custom position.
In fact, the cross icon (clear the user choice) must be just before the arrow of the dropdown.
How can I do this ?

[image]

EDIT : Resolved with position absolute